# How to link related questions across Stack exchange sites?

Tags: support, linked-questions

In [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/109286/72091) on dba.stackexchange I found two highly related questions on stackoverflow.  I put links in a comment pointing out the relationship, but I feel it would be more helpful if I could just add the links to the "Linked" section in the right sidebar below the jobs advertisement.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You're absolutely right this is a duplicate.  I wasn't able to find the question you linked when I searched.  Should I delete my question or leave it?

Comment: Leave it, might make it easier to find in the future. :)